# Electron menu not showing

Tags: javascript, electron

Following an electron tutorial and can't get the menus to show up on OS X. Checked that the menu object gets populated with menu items, they just don't appear either in the window or at the top of the screen. Html file loads just fine.

The only menu I see is the (default) app menu that reads Electron, but it has no content when clicked, not even empty lines - just nothing happens on click.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const mainWindowUrl = url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "html", "main.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true,
});

const menuTemplate = [
    {
        label: "File",
    },
    {
        label: "Menu1",
    },
    {
        label: "Menu2",
    },
];

const onAppReady = () => {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    mainWindow.loadURL(mainWindowUrl);

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
};

app.on("ready", onAppReady);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's just skipping your menus because they lack submenus, here is a modified version of your example that seems to work on my Mac:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const mainWindowUrl = url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "html", "main.html"),
    protocol: "file:",
    slashes: true
});
const menuTemplate = [
    {
        label: "File",
        submenu: [{role: 'TODO'}]
    },
    {
        label: "Menu1",
        submenu: [{role: 'TODO'}]
    },
    {
        label: "Menu2",
        submenu: [{role: 'TODO'}]
    }
];

const onAppReady = () => {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    mainWindow.loadURL(mainWindowUrl);

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
};

app.on("ready", onAppReady);
```

I don't know if it's an OSX specific thing but it appears that at least Electron doesn't like menus that directly trigger roles instead they must reveal submenus that can then trigger some action.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see anywhere that you needed any other content to make the valid menus. Makes sense though. I probably just missed it. :-)

Comment: My menu was not showing up because I had the call to `Menu.setApplicationMenu()` outside of that `on('ready')` function! Putting it inside worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

a solution for you

```
if (process.platform == 'darwin') {
    mainMenuTemplate.unshift({label: ''});
}
```

this may make some wrong

```
if (process.platform == 'darwin'){
    mainMenuTemplate.unshift({});
}
```

Comment: Yes, don't do `unshift({})`, it actually caused my application to not work at all. **So please emphasize that.**

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that on OS X the first menu item in your menu Template which is 'File' in your case is found under the default Electron Menu hence you might want to add an empty item in your array

```
const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {},
    {
        label: 'File',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'Add Item'
            },
            {
                label: 'Clear items'
            },
            {
                label: 'Quit',
                click(){
                    app.quit();
                }
            }
        ]
    }
 ];
```

Comment: This will result in menu spacing on the windows app. The best way is to read process.platform == 'darvin' and unshift an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

This it to fix the space needed on the nav for macosx

```
enter code here

//if mac add empty object to menuTemplate
if(process.platform=='darwin'){
  mainMenuTemplate.unshift({});//adding it to the beggining of the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added an empty menu with a role.

```
const mainMenuTemplate = [
{
  label: "",
  role: 'TODO'
},

{
    label: "File",

    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Add Item',
      },
      {
      label: 'Clear Items'
      }
    ]
}

];
```